# Is this a safe way of making user access level using PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, pdo

I am making a user access level in PHP. I wrote some code it worked and redirects the user to their respective pages, but I am not sure is it a safe way of doing it.

```
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "signin")){
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $password_1 = $_POST["password_1"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = :firstname";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(["firstname" => $firstname]);
    $res = $stmt->fetch();
    $password = $res["password_1"];

    if(password_verify($password_1, $password)){
        // USER ACCESS LEVEL
        if($res["user_type"] == "student"){
            $_SESSION["username"] = $firstname;
            header("location: index_s.php?type=student");
        } else if ($res["user_type"] == "teacher"){
            $_SESSION["username"] = $firstname;
            header("location: index_t.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION["username"] = $firstname;
            header("location: index.php");
        }
    } else {
        array_push($errors, "Invalid username/password entered!");
    }
}
```

I have a user_type column in my user table wherein user identifies which type of user he is while signing up and based on that they are redirected to their respective pages when they log in. 
However, this code works but I think this is not the right way of doing it. I need your help and feedback to improve the quality of my code. Also I am new in programming please explain clearly.

Comment: no need to put ```$_SESSION["username"] = $firstname;``` 3 times ... also why not verify the password in the query directly? (hopefully the password in the DB is encrypted and NOT MD5'd)

Comment: I think your way of role-based access control is fine enough for a simple system. Side note: why do you pass `type=student` when you already create a separate page for student users?

Comment: `type=student` was for testing purpose then I forgot to remove it

Comment: Book of Zeus, can you please write an answer how do I write `$_SESSION["username"] = $firstname;` only once and password is encrpyted and it is not MD%'d.

Answer (score -1):

Security is a huge topic and even major websites got hacked.

This being said I think **your solution is not safe**, because you're storing **plain passwords** in the database.

Furthermore you could do it all in one query. Something like:

```
$firstname = trim($_POST["firstname"]);
$password  = plain_password_to_hash(trim($_POST["password"])); // Important!

$sql = "SELECT id, user_type FROM users WHERE firstname = :firstname AND password = :password";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(["firstname" => $firstname, "password" => $password]);
$res = $stmt->fetch();

// If $res is empty, the combination of firstname and password wasn't found.
```

For **password security** please read:

1. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and
2. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php